# TControl parent problem when link with runtime library in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, parent-child, c++builder, vcl

I created a DLL and a Executable to perform a test.

So in the DLL, I created a Form2, which will receive the parent of Form1 that is in the Executable project.

When I uncheck the Packages-> Runtime packages-> link with runtime option (in the project settings),
and create Form2 through Form1, passing the parent of Form1 to Form2, Form2 is not shown on the screen !! And I use it
apply a parent-> visible = false, and in sequence a parent-> visible = true for Form2 to appear.

If I comment on the assignment of the parent of Form1 on Form2, Form2 also appears immediately.

And when I mark "link with runtime" option, Form2 appears normally !!

Why does this happen?

I have the template project in a shared folder:

[link to project sample](https://drive.google.com/open?id=149yPzR8ao6Svp5OJ4vDrWaUKRb7FfPHC)

Comment: Not an answer, but... Why oh why do I constantly see people putting forms in DLLs? If you want to do that, **use packages** for this. DLLs have different RTTI, different memory managers, etc. Packages don't. Packages were made for this.

Comment: in my case, it's simply a damn legacy!

Comment: If you have the code, it is easy to convert it to a package and to be happy about it.

Comment: I have the code. But it's a big project, I would have to recreate about 427 dlls

Comment: OK, I can feel the pain. <g>

Comment: 427 dlls for a single project ? that is crazy ...

Comment: Non-trivial types, like class objects, simply cannot be used safely across DLL boundaries. In this case, it is not just different RTTI or different instances of the memory manager, but more importantly different instances of the RTL library itself, particularly any globals it defines. That is exactly what Runtime Packages solves, by sharing a single instance of the RTL, RTTI, MM, etc across BPL boundaries.

Comment: I created a test project using BPL instead of DLL. And everything worked perfectly!
So the correct thing is not to create forms inside dlls? I see several delphi tutorials where this is done, and I believed that this was the right way to do it.

Comment: Note: This is a project made in Borland 6 and I am upgrading to Tokyo 10.2. This worked like this, in Borland 6, but it no longer works in C ++ Builder Tokyo.